# Boxplot involving qualitative and quantitative variables

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

I'm using "**d.pizza**" data. Among others, there is variable called "**delivery_min**" which is delivery time in minutes. The other variable is variable called "*area*" which can be one of three areas (Camden, Westminster
and Brent). I want to do boxplot, which compares delivery time in different areas.

I tried

```
boxplot(pizza_d~area", data = pizza_d$"delivery_min")
```

or `subset(pizza_d, pizza_d$"area" == "Brent","pizza_d$"delivery_min"")`

but it's not working

can I use "which" function in boxplot?

Comment: does `boxplot(delivery_min ~ area, data = d.pizza)` work? you should read the docs for boxplot and work through the examples

Comment: Yes, it does! It's part of a college assignment and I think it's way too difficult for us who barely knows basics.. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
library(DescTools)

data(d.pizza)

boxplot(delivery_min ~ area, data=d.pizza)
```

[image]

Comment: It's perfect ;) Thank you

Comment: Glad to help! Feel free to accept the answer or clarify your question if this does not fully resolve your problem.